# Typo3 v10.3: How to add an additional language into the system so that I can select that language in the site configuration

Tags: configuration, typo3

Constraints:

- Typo3 v10.3.0 with installation method "uploding zip file", not composer
- config.yaml see below has been autogenerated and I did not change

Problem I want solve:

Add an additional language - next to the default one - into the system so that I can select that language in the site configuration.

["See picture: Available Languages for this Site section" is empty, but I want to add English and Russian language to my site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFajL.jpg)

Neither in the site handling addingLanguages doc (1) nor in the tutorial (2) I found the description how to add a language to the system.

(1) https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/AddLanguages.html#sitehandling-addinglanguages

(2) https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-editors/master/en-us/Languages/Index.html

config.yaml

```yaml
base: 'https://<mysite>/autogenerated-1'
baseVariants: {  }
errorHandling: {  }
languages:
  -
    title: Deutsch
    enabled: true
    languageId: '0'
    base: 'https://<mysite>/'
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_DE.UTF8
    iso-639-1: de
    navigationTitle: Deutsch
    hreflang: de-DE
    direction: ltr
    flag: de
    websiteTitle: 'My Site'
rootPageId: 1
routes: {  }
websiteTitle: ''
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to define the available languages for the system first.

To do so, go to the list module, select the root node in the page tree (the one with the gray TYPO3 icon, id 0) and then in the top menu bar, click on the button with the `+` sign to create a new record. In the new record wizard, select the system record type `Website Language`. After creating a new website language record, the language is available in the site module.

The documentation about `Working with languages` can be found here: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-editors/master/en-us/Languages/Index.html

Feel free to request a change in the documentation using the button on the top right side `Edit on GitHub`.

Comment: I followed your approach and now I could see the language which I have added in the site configuration. I guess in the tutorial (2 on my question) the part with adding the Website language is missing. They assume that the website language section is already there: "Use the WEB > List view and place yourself on the “New TYPO3 Site” page. Scroll down a bit, until you see the list of “Website Languages”."

Comment: Thanks, we added a cross reference to the mentioned part of the docs. So people should be guided through the process more smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being it is necessary to add a record of type "Website Language" (`sys_language`) for each language in the backend.

This is a little inconsistency but that's where the Site Config UI gets the available languages from.

You probably can also just add the language configuration to the .yaml and I am pretty sure the frontend would be fine with that, but I am not sure if the backend might still need a real `sys_language` record.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I could solve my problem by adding the "New language" on the root node in the page tree. See my comment to the answer above.

Comment: Christian then please accept and rate up Chistian's answer.